# UFT is not recognizing web objects for web based application developed using sharepoint 2013

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, hp-uft

When I tried using object spy but for links,webList etc for all the objects it is recognizing all of them as webElement. I have tried by adding .dot addin, I think I am missing something other than this.
This application is developed using Sharepoint 2013 and UI part is totally developed using angular js.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Please improve your question by f.e. including the html of a simple sample page, and other details. You won´t receive useful feedback otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If they are recognized as WebElement, you can handle them as webelements. You can write a function to dynamically recognize your element, and use appropriate method (Set, Select...etc).

Screenshots or object details might help here.